# How to mock DriverManager.getConnection?

Tags: java, jdbc, mocking, mockito

How do I mock the DriverManager.getConnection() method?

I want to test my method setUpConnectiontoDB()

I tried it with PowerMock, easyMock and Mokito itself. I didn't find anything usefull.

My Code:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class MysqlDAO implements DAO {
    private final Properties properties = new Properties();

    public MysqlDAO(String configPath) {
        loadProperties(configPath);
    }

    private Properties loadProperties(String configPath) {
        try {
            properties.load(new FileInputStream(configPath));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return this.properties;
    }

    @Override
    public Connection setUpConnectionToDB() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            return DriverManager.getConnection(
                    properties.getProperty("url"),
                    properties.getProperty("user"),
                    properties.getProperty("passwd"));

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: you didn't provided your trial ? and what did you meant by **I didn't find anything useful** ? Pick any one out of those three frameworks and lets us know what challenge you face? by the way, I am not the down voter :) Its a valid question provided you describe it properly with all needed information.

Comment: At the moment I am doing an apprenticeship at the moment and I am learning about TTD. I want to test the setUpConnectionToDB() method, so it is correctly makes a working connection. Yes I can just test it by connection a my local MYSQL but this is not the point. Because when I build my project and deploy it. There will be no testing MYSQL. So I tried to mock only this method. Not the upcoming statement I have to prepare. Or doesn't make this any seance?

Comment: mock returns a fake object so if you mock `DriverManager.getConnection()`, your `Connection` object will be a fake one and you will not be able to perform any **real** tasks on that `Connection` object. In memory DB suggested by **Jan** is the way to go if you want to do DB data verifications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some notes on that:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

This line is obsolete since JDBC 4.0. You should be able to run the code without. Or if you think you need it at least abstract it as well to do

```
Class.forName(properties.getProperty("dbdriver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Once that's been taken care of, *who says you have to mock it*? It's much easier to actually run it.

You could just as well use an in memory database (like h2) for testing and check your code for that. All you'd change would be your url, user and passwd properties.

This would be some example properties for use with [h2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html):

```
dbdriver = org.h2.Driver
url = jdbc:h2:mem:test
user = sa
passwd = sa
```

That way, you not only take care of your unit-test for setUpConnectionToDB() but could later *use* that connection for methods that expect some data in that database.

Comment: +1 for using a real, in-memory database because it will be easier than mocking one.  As an another option besides h2 you can try Derby Embedded which is very easy to set up and also has in-mem databases.
 https://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html